# Cannot load "Directions" modules for Bing Maps in Visual Studio (Windows 8)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, bing-maps

I'm pretty new to Windows 8 app development. I've got a decent "Hello World" program up and running in Visual Studio. I'm using the Javascript API.

I'm facing problems while loading the modules. I cannot load the "Microsoft.Maps.Directions" module specifically.

"Microsoft.Maps.Map" is loading without any problems and I can display a map with no issues. But whenever I try to load the other modules, my app crashes.

Am I overlooking something really obvious here? Do I need to download some extra libraries or something? I've already downloaded the Bing Maps AJAX Control 7 SDK and I'm using it to display the map.

Thanks!

My code:

```
//Initialization logic for loading the map control
(function () {
    function initialize() {
        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', { callback: Testing});
        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Map', { callback: GetMap });
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initialize, false);
})();


//This works
function GetMap() {
    var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog('Maps Loaded!');
    messageDialog.showAsync();
});

//This doesn't work
function Testing() {
    var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog('Directions Loaded!!');
    messageDialog.showAsync();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you are using the [Bing Maps SDK for Windows 8](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb764f67-6b2c-4e14-b2d3-17477ae1eaca).

Second, make sure you are loading the modules script file prior to making an use of the Maps API.

```
<script src="/Bing.Maps.JavaScript/js/veapicore.js"></script>
<script src="/Bing.Maps.JavaScript/js/veapiModules.js"></script>
```

The second script tag is critical here since it is what enables the use of the "secondary" modules like Directions.  It is not called out in the docs very well that veapiModules.js needs to be loaded for those modules to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff. I think this was the problem. Cheers! :)